# Xcode. Image resources added to a test target are not copied into the tests bundle

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I wrote some extension to `UIImage` class and want to cover it by Unit Tests. I added some image to test target and checked that it presents in the `Copy Bundle Resources` list. 
[image: Copy Bundle Resources]

In the test code I use a model object which pvovides me test data.

```
class TestConstants {
    private static var bundle: Bundle {
        return Bundle(for: UIImageExtensionsTests.self)
    }
    private static var birdImageURL: URL {
        let path = self.bundle.url(forResource: "birds", withExtension: "png")
        return path!
    }
    static var birdImageData: Data {
        return try! Data(contentsOf: self.birdImageURL)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `birds.png` image is not located in test bundle, but another resource `drm.txt` presents. 
[image]
[image]
I'm a bit confused is it the bug in Xcode?
By the way I downloaded Xcode 9.4 beta and there are the same behavior - images do not copy into the test bundle.

[image]

**#UPDATE**:

`UIImageExtensionsTests` is a test class presents in the same target with `drm.txt` and `birds.png` file

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is `UIImageExtensionsTests`?

Comment: Added details about `UIImageExtensionsTests`. It's test class presents in the test target

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. Infact I tried it out for myself and my test runs just fine. Maybe clean and build the tests target, then run the test and if there's still some error then add the exact error message to your question.

Comment: @staticVoidMan did you add image resource in test target? Because with txt file there is no the issue. But only with `png` file

Comment: yes, i did add. the image should be added to your test target and in your case it does seem to be added. right?

Comment: No, all resources are in the target. The issue was with "wrong" image founded in the internet. I just took first displayed image after googling text "image" :) Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

To get the appropriate Bundle use :

```
 let bundle = Bundle.init(for: TestConstants.classForCoder())
```

Comment: But how does it solve the issue that image resources absent in test bundle?

Comment: Tje image are in the bundle, it's just the way you fetch it which fails

Comment: I took screenshot that there is not `birds.png` file in the test bundle. I'm able to get access to `drm.txt`, but can't to `birds.png`
And TestConstants is not a subclass of `NSObject`, so it doesn't conform `NSCoding` protocol and unable to call `classForCoder`

Answer (score 0):

My bad that I didn't read log carefully.
The issue was happen with "wrong" image founded in internet. Xcode couldn't proceed image, so it didn't copy it to test bundle.

> While reading
>   /Users/igork/developer/gitlab/ios.gym-master/GymMasterTests/Resources/birds.png
>   pngcrush caught libpng error:    Not a PNG file..

[image]

And this error doesn't fail building and running the target. So in my case the tests were starting :(

Comment: aah... this is the kind of information you put in your question.