# Xcode 10: Load the same .xml file in project target and unit test target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, unit-testing

I try to load the same .xml file in project target and unit test target.

It seems to be a similar problem like this question: [Xcode. Image resources added to a test target are not copied into the tests bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794276/xcode-image-resources-added-to-a-test-target-are-not-copied-into-the-tests-bund?rq=1)

In project target, this code snipped worked fine. I just have to add the "xmlString.xml" file to "Copy Files" (see image 1).

```
func parseFile() {
   let stringPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "xmlString", ofType: "xml")
   let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: stringPath!)
   ...
}
```

[image: Image1]

If I run the code snipped in unit test target, I get an error because the .xml file can not be found. I tried to add the .xml file to the "Copy Bundle Resources" without any success (see image 2).

[image: image 2]

The only way to get it working is to use the absolute path

```
func parseFile() {
   let stringPath: String? = "/Users/.../Documents/Git/.../.../.../.../xmlString.xml"
   let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: stringPath!)
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to use the `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "xmlString", ofType: "xml")` function instead of the absolute path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the bundle for your project like this:

```
let projectBundle = Bundle(for: AnyClassInMyProject.self)
```

where you replace `AnyClassInMyProject` with the name of an actual class in your project.

You can then get the path to your .xml file like this:

```
let stringPath = projectBundle.path(forResource: "xmlString", ofType: "xml")
```

Comment: let projectBundle = NSBundle </Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pattern-chlgsqhxjngcwabmjgaujwwewapq/Build/Products/Debug/UnitTest.xctest> (loaded) what to do with this information?

Comment: Did you replace `AnyClassInMyProject` with the name of an actual class in your project? Your main project, not your test project? If so, `projectBundle` will refer to the bundle for your main project, i.e. it will be the equivalent of calling Bundle.main in your main project.

Comment: Yes, I replaced "AnyClassInMyProject" with my XmlParser class in main project. So it seems to be completely wrong right? But why does it work in main target and not in test target? What do I have to change?